# Attitude of a homework vampire

Tags: discussion

I am referring to [this comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/which-one-of-the-following-schemes-of-ordering-closed-pack-sheets-of-equal-sized?noredirect=1#comment49901_33327), which states:

> And @santiago I know that it is on me to think about it but what to do when I'm not even able to understand where to start ? KlausWarzecha gave me the answer. **So even if you close the question i dont care as i know the answer now.**

Which basically is the "I got what I want, so I don't care about your rules" petulant attitude that the true homework vampire exhibits.

I believe that this is a major reason why we should not help any homework questions until they show some effort first. It does not help the student to 'spoon feed' answers.

Comment: I understand that this situation is not pleasant. Just stay calm, relax, don't engage in a discussion. Walk away keep your head up high. These people will come frequently and with the site still growing, there will be more and more of them. Just give the question a down vote, a flag, and relax.

Comment: Absolutely! I figure I will do my usual homework greeting and link to the Be Nice policy if needed - flag and find something to answer.

Comment: Oh, I somehow missed this, and the drama. Again. **Shame on me!**

Comment: Mmmm... Blade 4: Release The Santiago! Where is my popcorn? :D

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani is in charge of that

Comment: **Homework Vampire** - Vote for the jargon.